# tex4ht does not handle \ifdefined\HCode in mathjax mode

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax

This is  issue with tex4ht only.

This is the first time I found where tex4ht does not process `\ifdefined\HCode`.

I put `\ifdefined\HCode` inside an equation, since I need different code for HTML vs. pdf mode.

`tex4ht` does not process the `ifdefined` and leave it there. When `mathjax` sees it, it complains since mathjax offcourse does not know anything about `ifdefined\HCode`.

When the code is compiled not using `mathjax` it works OK. But I need to use `mathjax`.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\[
\ifdefined\HCode 
     \left[
     \begin{array}{ccc}
\else 
     \left[
     \begin{array}{@{}cc|c@{}}
\fi 
       3 i&-3 &0\\ 
       3 &3 i &0
    \end{array}
    \right]               
\]
test
\end{document}
```

The above compiled OK using `lualatex foo3.tex` and gives

[image]

But compiling using `make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo3.tex "mathjax,htm"` it gives

[image]

This is the raw HTML. it shows the `\ifdefined\HCode` was not processed and left in there

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" > 
<head><title></title> 
<meta  charset="utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foo3.css" /> 
<meta name="src" content="foo3.tex" /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ], displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ], processEscapes: true, processEnvironments: true, packages: ['base', 'color', 'ams'] }, loader: { load: ['[tex]/color', '[tex]/ams'] } }; </script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" async="async" id="MathJax-script" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js"></script>  
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 23--><p class="noindent" >\[ \ifdefined \HCode \left [ \begin{array}{ccc} \else \left [ \begin{array}{@{}cc|c@{}} \fi 3 i&amp;-3 &amp;0\\ 3 &amp;3 i &amp;0 \end{array} \right ] \]
</p><!--l. 25--><p class="indent" >   test
</p>   
 
</body> 
</html>
```

Compiled using `make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo3.tex "htm"` works with no problem and gives

[image]

The problems seems that tex4ht does not look inside the equation to see that there is something to do, and just passes the whole thing to `mathjax`.

### UPDATE

I found workaround. Which is to put `\ifdefined\HCode` outside everything, and duplicate the whole code twice, including the `array` code. I was hoping to avoid this.  But this works for now. For some reason, putting `\ifdefined\HCode` inside any equation does not work with tex4ht when in `mathjax` mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\ifdefined\HCode %tex4ht version
 \[
 \left[
     \begin{array}{ccc}
    3 i&-3&0\\ 
    0  &0 &0
     \end{array}
  \right]               
\]
\else %PDF version
\[
 \left[
     \begin{array}{@{}cc|c@{}}
    3 i&-3&0\\ 
    0  &0 &0
     \end{array}
  \right]               
\]
\fi 

\end{document}
```

TL 2020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX4ht of course cannot interpret your code inside math environments, because they are passed to HTML code verbatim. They are interpreted by MathJax when you display the HTML code and MathJax of course doesn't know anything about `\ifdefined\HCode`, so it ignores it. You either need to duplicate your code and let LaTeX interpret your code, or you can try to use a custom environment and pass an alternative definition to  MathJax. Which may or may not work.

For example, this seems to work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\mathjaxalt[2]{#2}
\begin{document}
\[
 \mathjaxalt{%
     \left[
     \begin{array}{ccc}
     }{%
     \left[
     \begin{array}{@{}cc|c@{}}
     }%
       3 i&-3 &0\\ 
       3 &3 i &0
    \end{array}
    \right]               
\]
test
\end{document}
```

I've defined the `\mathjaxalt` macro, which takes two parameters, first contains code for MathJax, second contains code for regular LaTeX. You need to provide a definition of this macro for MathJax in a config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{MathJaxConfig}{{
    tex: {
      tags: "ams",
      \detokenize{%
      inlineMath: [ ["\\\(","\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ]},
      processEscapes: true,
      processEnvironments: true,
      macros: {
        mathjaxalt: ["\#1",2],
      }
  },
  loader: {
    load: ['[tex]/color', '[tex]/ams']
  }
};
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the definition:

```
macros: {
   mathjaxalt: ["\#1",2],
}
```

It uses the first parameter, as opposed to the original definition, which uses the second parameter.

This is how it is rendered in HTML:

[image]